# How to save window position in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, dialog

When i open **File structure** Dialog (that can he opened at <kbd>Ctrl + F12</kbd> shortcut) in the start position on my monitor i have a problem.

I try **drag and drop this window** to my comfort position. **After that i close him** ( i think that helps, but it's not)- **the dialog showing up in start position**, **not in position related on my decision**. How i can save my dialog position? Because it's so irritation.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ IDEA are you running? What OS? I get the behavior you desire in IDEA 13 on Windows. I know that some Linux GUI shells are problematic (in general - not sure about this issue specifically.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me on Android Studio 2.2.3, but should do for IntelliJ IDEA:

On the menu bar: `Window` > `Store Current Layout as Default`

**+ Update ( 2017 - Sep - 24 )**

When using `Windowed Mode` the above failed. So I had to do the following.

First, choose what `Tool Window` you be setting up. For example `1: Project`.

1. **Left**-click the item to show it
2. *Right*-click the item and select `Windowed Mode`
3. Choose the window position that you like
4. **Left**-click again, to close it.
5. To make sure, **left**-click again, to open it.
6. Finally, select on the menu bar `Window` > `Store Current Layout as Default`

Restart the IDE to check, but it should work.

This was tested on `AndroidStudio 2.3.3` and `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4` with 2 monitor screens (displays).

Answer (score 2):

As of now 2020 September you can do this via creating a new branch in git for the same project.

So lets say you have Branch A to use view/setup for one task. When you create branch B you can then change this view/setup, because when you switch back to branch A, your setup there (which window is on left/right, etc.) will be restored.